# Main Nav Colour in Luna Theme

Tags: navigation, bigcartel

This is my website - http://www.afternoons.com.au

I have been trying to change the main nav colour to an orange when it is rolled over and when a page is clicked on. I have figured out you have to change the 'text' colour in the backend customization BUT this also changes the text of the product descriptions.

Is there a way to override the **CSS** so that the product descriptions remain grey, while the main nav can rollover to orange and stay orange when clicked on?

Comment: Are you aware you should be able to apply different styles to different things and change the text color only for a certain style?  (It's not clear if that's the issue or if the issue is that bigcartel doesn't provide that for reasons beyond my ken)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Hi Foon, yes this is something I can do (and want to do) my currently using Luna theme I am unable to do this and Big Cartel cannot provide advice for how to do this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the hover color of the Luna theme's navigation bar links by adding the following CSS at the very bottom of Customize Design > Advanced > CSS:

```
#main_nav li a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Just replace the color with whatever you'd like and you're all set. Then to activate the "selected" class for every category page, you can do the following:

Everywhere you have a link like this in the Layout code:

```
<li><a href="http://www.afternoons.com.au/category/vessels">Vessels</a></li>
```

You need to replace it using the following format:

```
<li {% if page.full_url contains '/category/vessels' %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="/category/vessels">Vessels</a></li>
```

And finally, you'll need to use this CSS:

```
#main_nav li a:hover, #main_nav li.selected a { 
  color: #FF0000
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you! Is there a way of keeping the chosen hover colour when the link is selected?

Comment: Is this an active or selected link or something? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect!